# Getting all addition and subtraction combinations of a list python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I am trying to find all of the addition and subtraction combinations of a list of numbers. I want to create a recursive function that does this, but I am having trouble conceptualizing how this would work. This is my code right now

```
from itertools import permutations
values = [1, 2]
perm = []

size = 1
while size <= len(values):
    perm += permutations(values, size)
    size = size + 1

for i in perm:
    someFuntion(i)
```

I want the output to be this for the given list.

```
(1)
(2)
(1 + 2)
(1 - 2)
(2 + 1)
(2 - 1)
```

Can someone help me conceptualize how I would write "someFunction"?

Edit: So I updated my function and it works for lists of size 2, but I'm having trouble with larger lists. Can you help explain how you return a list without passing one into the function?

```
def some_function(i, results):

    # Base case
    if len(i) == 0:
        return 
    # Base case
    elif len(i) == 1:

        if i[0] not in results:
            results.append(i[0])

        return i[0]

    else:

        topVal = str(i.pop(0))

        plus = topVal + " + " + str(some_function(i, results))
        minus = topVal + " - " + str(some_function(i, results))
        results.append(plus)
        results.append(minus)


results = []
possibilities = list(flatten(map(lambda s: list(permutations(s)), powerset(values))))

for p in possibilities:
    some_function(list(p), results)

print(results)
```

This is my output for a list = [1, 2, 3]

```
['1', '2', '3', '1 + 2', '1 - 2', '2 + 1', '2 - 1', '1 + 3', '1 - 3', '3 + 1', '3 - 1', '2 + 3', '2 - 3', '3 + 2', '3 - 2', '2 + 3', '2 - 3', '1 + None', '1 - 3', '3 + 2', '3 - 2', '1 + None', '1 - 2', '1 + 3', '1 - 3', '2 + None', '2 - 3', '3 + 1', '3 - 1', '2 + None', '2 - 1', '1 + 2', '1 - 2', '3 + None', '3 - 2', '2 + 1', '2 - 1', '3 + None', '3 - 1']
```

Edit 2: I figured it out based on your second edit. Thanks for taking the time to walk me through this. I think this will help me write recursive functions better in the future.

Comment: `res = ["(" + (f" {s} ").join(str(c) for c in comb) + ")" for comb in permutations(values) for s in signs]`

Comment: ^ That doesn't include subsets.

Comment: @Chase See my "edit 2" based on your "edit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking define a function `some_function` such that

```
from itertools import chain, permutations
from more_itertools import powerset, flatten

values = [1, 2]
signs = ["+", "-"]
possibilities = list(flatten(map(lambda s: list(permutations(s)), powerset(values))))

list(flatten([some_function(p) for p in possibilities]))
```

outputs

```
['', '1', '2', '1 + 2', '1 - 2', '2 + 1', '2 - 1']
```

I have managed to define the function recursively in 8 lines. The outline of which looks like the following. Note you can probably collapse the first two bases into one.

```
def some_function(i):
    if <base case>:
        # Base case
    elif <second base case>:
        # Base case
    else:
        # Recursive case
```

The key is to realize that you need to return a list of strings each time no matter which case you go into. For the recursive case, you want to deal with the first integer in the tuple and then trust in the recursion to handle the remainder. And then combine the first integer with the remainder using one of the possible signs. It also may be helpful to know how to interpolate strings and use list comprehensions (or flatten).

Edit: See comments below. The output of [1,2,3] is as follows:

```
['',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '1 + 2',
 '1 - 2',
 '2 + 1',
 '2 - 1',
 '1 + 3',
 '1 - 3',
 '3 + 1',
 '3 - 1',
 '2 + 3',
 '2 - 3',
 '3 + 2',
 '3 - 2',
 '1 + 2 + 3',
 '1 + 2 - 3',
 '1 - 2 + 3',
 '1 - 2 - 3',
 '1 + 3 + 2',
 '1 + 3 - 2',
 '1 - 3 + 2',
 '1 - 3 - 2',
 '2 + 1 + 3',
 '2 + 1 - 3',
 '2 - 1 + 3',
 '2 - 1 - 3',
 '2 + 3 + 1',
 '2 + 3 - 1',
 '2 - 3 + 1',
 '2 - 3 - 1',
 '3 + 1 + 2',
 '3 + 1 - 2',
 '3 - 1 + 2',
 '3 - 1 - 2',
 '3 + 2 + 1',
 '3 + 2 - 1',
 '3 - 2 + 1',
 '3 - 2 - 1']
```

Edit 2:

Let us first do some clean up. Try to get comfortable with list indexing; you will probably use it a lot. `i[0]` means get the head of the list. `i[1:]` means get everything else (the tail). Also as much as possible don't think about mutating; you'll just make the problem harder than it needs to be. You can use append to build up a list locally but don't pass in the list into the another function (including recursively) and hope to mutate it correctly. Here is the result of my clean up. You're almost there!

```
def some_function(i):
    if len(i) == 0:
        return [""]
    elif len(i) == 1:
        return [str(i[0])]
    else:
        head = str(i[0])
        results = some_function(i[1:])
        # ...
        for result in results:
            plus = head + " + " + result
            minus = head + " - " + result
            # ...
        return ...
```

Start with the handling of a simple tuple like `(1,2)`. Try thinking `results` to be the return of the base case (e.g., `["2"]`) and see if you can "build up" the next case (e.g., `["1 + 2", "1 - 2"]`) from there.

Comment: Does your function pass other values in besides the tuple?

Comment: Just the tuple indeed. As you can see from my first snippet, you'll probably need to do a tad bit of "post-processing" to get the final output as a list of strings.

Comment: I tried a solution where I base my base_cases around the size of the tuple I pass in and then I modify the tuple in the recursive case, but that's doesn't work. Also if you only pass in a tuple to the function, I'm not sure how to incorporate the signs array. Do you mind giving me a more of a hint?

Comment: You're on the right track! Indeed my first two base cases were when `len(i) == 0` and `len(i) == 1`.

Comment: Ah yes, I might have mislead you slightly. I do indeed use `signs` as a global variable.

Comment: Also since you only have two `signs` you could just manually write it out like `[f"... + ...", f"... - ..."]`. The `...` is stuff you'll need to fill in.

Comment: I'm close to a solution. I was just wondering, does this method work for lists of values > 2?

Comment: Yes it does. I'll update my answer to show the output of `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Also if you're still stuck, feel free to edit your question to show your progress.